# Does the entire certificate chain need to be signed with the agreed upon cipher under TLS?

Tags: tls, openssl, sha, cipher-selection

Security Newbie,
I'm using OpenSSL for my client, and noticed that when testing it against [Bad ssl's sha1-intermediate test](https://sha1-intermediate.badssl.com/), it accepts it although the agreed upon cipher is `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)`. I had to set the security level for OpenSSL to `2` using [SSL_CTX_get_security_level](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_get_security_level.html) in order to block this.

By examining the Wireshark data for [Bad ssl's sha1-intermediate test](https://sha1-intermediate.badssl.com/), I saw that the leaf certificate is signed with `sha256WithRSAEncryption`, and the intermediate certificate is signed with `sha1WithRSAEncryption` (as stated in the `algorithmIdentifier` section).

As far as I understand, signing the intermediate certificate with `sha1` does not comply with the cipher suite agreed upon in the intial stage of the TLS handshake..

Does this mean that the cipher suite only applies to the leaf certificate, and for blocking the `sha1` intermediate certificate I have to use OpenSSL's security level feature?

Thanks in advance,
David.

Comment: TLS cipher suites are completely different things than what certificates are signed with. Why do you think they should have anything in common?

Comment: Well, sorry, I'm a newbie.. Wrong assumption.. Maybe it has to do with [SSL_CTX_set1_client_sigalgs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SSL_CTX_set1_client_sigalgs.html) and not [SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html). I'll try that path. Thank you :)